# Index out of bounds (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, cycle

Iam trying to get the value for p(4) (sorry for this)

The equation is looking like this:
4800+p1+p2*z/1000+p3*e^(-p4*z/1000)

I keep getting this error:
Attempted to access p(4); index out of bounds because numel(p)=3.

Error in waves (line 32)
xy1 = 4800+5.6596+14.5820/1000*xs+257.4318*exp(-p(4)/1000);

How can i change the "bounds" in numel or is there any else i can do to fix this problem?

**The code**

```
z = [0.0; 500; 1000; 1500; 2000; 2500; 3000; 3500; 4000; 5000; 6000; 7000; 8000; 9000; 10000; 11000; 12000];
y = [5050 4980 4930 4890 4870 4865 4860 4860 4865 4875 4885 4905 4920 4935 4950 4970 4990]'-4800 ;
A = [ones(numel(z),1) z./1000 exp(-z./1000)];
p = A\y;
norm(p);
y = y+4800;

xs = 0:1:12000;
xy = 4800+5.6596+14.5820/1000*xs+257.4318*exp(-p(4)/1000);
subplot(2,2,4), plot(z,y,'o')
hold on
subplot(2,2,4), plot(xs,xy);
title('p4')
```

Edit:::::::

I had this first, where p4 had a start guess(value) (p4=1), i then put the p1,p2,p3 results in a new file to try to solve p4, thats the code above.

```
z = [0.0; 500; 1000; 1500; 2000; 2500; 3000; 3500; 4000; 5000; 6000; 7000; 8000; 9000; 10000; 11000; 12000];
y = [5050 4980 4930 4890 4870 4865 4860 4860 4865 4875 4885 4905 4920 4935 4950 4970 4990]'-4800 ;
A = [ones(numel(z),1) z./1000 exp(-z./1000)];
p = A\y;
norm(p);
y = y+4800;

xs = 0:1:12000;
xy = 4800+p(1)+p(2)/1000*xs+p(3)*exp(-xs/1000);
subplot(2,2,1), plot(z,y,'o')
hold on
subplot(2,2,1), plot(xs,xy);
title('p1,p2,p3')
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here ? well since `A` is a `17 x 3` here and `y` is `17 x 1`, `p` would be `3 x 1` and you are trying to access `p(4)` which does not exist.

Comment: I am trying to get the value for p(4)

Comment: So you expect `p` to be a `4 x 1` matrix ? Can you explain what p is supposed to be ?

Comment: Yeah thats correct (4x1) because of the first thing you said (3x1) and p(4) is then missing. p is just a variable but should result in 1.* something

Comment: Are you trying to solve the equation `y = A*p` for the vector `p`? Or are you trying to divide the values in `A` by those in `y` (as @Huguenot suggests)?

Comment: I actually deleted my answer given that this is starting to look a bit more like a curve fitting problem.

Comment: But if it were a curve fitting problem, you would change `p(4)` to `xs`

Comment: Huguenot thats true.. The p4 i get is not fitting the curve at all.. I updated the thread a little..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Armed with the knowledge that you are trying to fit the model described here:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/214797/soundwaves-under-the-water

i.e. `f(z) = 4800 + p1 + p2*z/1000 + p3*exp(-z*p4/1000)`

The problem is this it is a non linear equation, so you cannot simply use the MATLAB backslash operator.  You will need to do what the answer suggests and look into using `lsqnonlin` in optimzation toolbox or fit a custom equation in Curve Fitting Toolbox.

Personally, I am biased towards Curve Fitting Toolbox, and I would do the following with cftool:

[image]

Here we can see that the coefficient estimates are:

```
   p1 =      -20.21  (-29.34, -11.08)
   p2 =       17.34  (16.31, 18.36)
   p3 =       272.9  (263.3, 282.5)
   p4 =      0.7528  (0.6964, 0.8092)
```

Bear in mind that I have quite loose lower and upper bounds.  If you wanted to make sure that p1 was always positive, you could do that by setting the lower bound to zero.

Comment: Thats how i did from the beginning, i updated the first post. The problem is to get the real value for p4. I pasted the equation in the first post if you can see it.

Comment: so if we consider your model as `f(z) = p(1)*exp(-z/1000) + p(2)*z/1000 + p(3)`, where would you place p(4)

Comment: `p(4) = p(1)*exp(-z/1000) + p(2)*z/1000 + p(3)` ?

Comment: The problem is that the expression `p(1)*exp(-z/1000) + p(2)*z/1000 + p(3)` is not a constant, because `f(z)` depends on what value of `z` you feed into it.  This means that p(4) is not a constant value.  This is in contrast to `p(1)`, `p(2)` and `p(1)` which are constants that you find using the backslash operator.  The good news, is that you've might have already solved your problem.  You've fitted a pretty good model to your data, and you've shown (via a plot) how it closely maps to `z` and `y`.  What else do you feel you need to show?

Comment: I need the correct value for p4 because in the beginning the p4 is set to 1 as a start guess value and i need to get the real value for p4

Comment: I think we may need an explanation in your post of what the original question was.  I'm afraid it's still not clear to me what you mean by p(4).

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/214797/soundwaves-under-the-water here you can see the question hehe

Comment: Argh, so that is a non-linear equation and you can't use backslash.  I will update my answer, but you'll need access to either optimization toolbox or curve fitting toolbox.

Comment: Yeah i have access to that in matlab

Comment: Strange that i dont get the same results like you do. Where do you change the lower bound so that it will show a positive value?

Comment: You click on Fit Options and edit the row for the unknown that you are interested in

Comment: What values do you get when you change the lower bound to zero?